# Apache Nifi - update postgre record using ST_GeomFromText

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi, postgis

I am using postgre PostGIS extension to update polygon data in a table.
Below is my query:

```
update address
set location_polygon=ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-73.974023 40.785093, -73.966443 40.785093, -73.966443 40.772525, -73.974023 40.772525, -73.974023 40.785093))', 4326)
where id='columbus'
```

while I can do this using the Postgre client, I wonder how I can do the same using the Apache NIFI putDatabase record processor.
The processor looks like below:
[image]

As you can see this insert location_polygon in string format an I want it stored using `ST_GeomFromText`